# Having multiple time-out periods for different pages in Wicket?

Tags: java, properties, web, timeout, wicket

I'm using Wicket 1.5 and I'm wanting to have a different time out period set for different pages.

Say on the "My Profile" screen, I would want the timeout period to be longer than the timeout period for the "change password" screen. At the moment the timeout property is set in the server properties and is the same for every page.

Could I set the property somewhere else, just for the change password screen or other selected screens? If I could do this, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this is not possible as the session timeout is handled by the servlet container. You can specify it in the web.xml.

You may fake it by storing the time the page was rendered and compare it with the time the form is submitted.